# Bewildering Python output

Tags: python, list, append, counter

I have the following loop which prevents duplicate users from being stored in the same list indexed by hour:

```
for row in rows:
     cur_epoch_time = (row['tweet_time'] - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
     cur_time = cur_epoch_time - min_epoch_time
     hour = math.floor(cur_time/interval_length)
     curUserID = row['source_user_id']
     if curUserID not in di_users[int(hour)]:
         idx_counts[int(hour)] += 1
         di_users[int(hour)].append(curUserID)

return (idx_counts, di_users, d_counts, ints)
```

We should expect that `len(di_users[int(hour)]) == idx_counts[int(hour)]` surprisingly they are not equal! In fact it is always the case that, `sum(idx_counts[int(hour)]) == len(di_users[int(hour)])`

Here is an example output:

```
di = FUNCTION_CALL()
>>> lens = [len(di[1][h]) for h in xrange(25)]
>>> lens
[2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724, 2724]
>>> di[0]
{0: 126, 1: 185, 2: 167, 3: 154, 4: 194, 5: 190, 6: 190, 7: 174, 8: 146, 9: 158, 10: 130, 11: 113, 12: 139, 13: 105, 14: 92, 15: 81, 16: 58, 17: 31, 18: 49, 19: 39, 20: 35\
, 21: 32, 22: 52, 23: 84, 24: 0}
>>> sum(di[0].values())
2724
```

1. Shouldn't the count be the same as the length of the list?
2. What is wrong? Or what can I do to fix this problem?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: It's hard to know anything without seeing how `idx_counts` and `di_users` are initialized.  My first thought is that `sum(idx_counts[int(hour)])` should raise `TypeError: int not iterable` if `idx_counts` was a list of integers ...

Comment: both `idx_counts` and `di_users` are dictionaries and have the same key-set: the list of integers from 0 to 24. Note that I have included sample output.

Comment: Yes, but you still haven't showed how you *initialized* them.  Did you use `dict.fromkeys`?  Did you use a loop, a dict-comp?  Can you show that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that you've initialzed your `di_users` dict *with the same list*.  e.g.

```
di_users = dict.fromkeys(xrange(25), [])
```

Notice:

```
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(xrange(4), [])
>>> d[0].append(1)
>>> d
{0: [1], 1: [1], 2: [1], 3: [1]}
```

This is because `d[0]` is the same list as `d[1]` and `d[2]`.

```
>>> d[0] is d[1] is d[2] is d[3]
True
```

Appending do `d[0]` also appends to `d[1]` etc. because they're just references to the same list.

Another way that might happen is:

```
lst = []
di_users = {}
for i in xrange(25):
    di_users[i] = lst
```

You need to make a *new* list for each element in `di_users`.  One easy way to do this would be to use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
di_users = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Or, you could use a plain old dictionary-comprehension:

```
di_users = {k: [] for k in xrange(25)}  # python2.7
```

Or a generator expression if you really need to for python 2.6 compatibility:

```
di_users = dict((k,[]) for k in xrange(25))
```